# Stack multi header in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, stack

I have a problem with stacking the following multi header table:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    
header = [np.array(['A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C']), 
np.array(['a','b','c','x','y','z','x','y','H'])] 
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 9), index=['0','1','2','3','4'], columns = header )
df
```

The table looks like the follwoing:

```
     A                                   B                                   C
            a           b           c           x          y            z           x           y           H
0   -1.866417   -1.157851   -0.686079   -2.207161   0.674927     1.461270    0.111046   -1.002747    1.779708
1    0.703842   -0.952045   -0.276650   -0.545629  -0.051884     0.255752   -0.438207   -0.772825   -0.583204
```

For the names in the multi header B and C applies x=x, y=y, z=/H

I want to transform the table to the following format:

```
                   a            b           c           x          y           z           H
0     B    -1.866417    -1.157851   -0.686079   -2.207161    0.674927    1.461270        NaN
1     B     0.703842    -0.952045   -0.276650   -0.545629   -0.051884    0.255752        NaN
3     C    -1.866417    -1.157851   -0.686079    1.037115    0.111046   -1.002747         NaN   1.779708
4     C     0.703842    -0.952045   -0.276650   -0.438207   -0.772825         NaN  -0.583204
```

That means, the "over-header" "A" can be dropped because I don`t need it, I just need the columns from that header "a" "b" and "c".

I used several approaches with .stack .unstack set_index etc. but could not find the right solution.

Any ideas on how I can get this done?

Best
Jerry

Comment: just a suggestion, when sharing data involving random, it helps to set a seed, that way, it is reproducible. Also, how come the values in column x seem to be swapped with d values in z?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the suggestions. I will make sure to do it with the seed next time. I also corrected the values in the columns. Is it clearer now?

Comment: when u flip B and C into index columns, where do the values for a and b come from. e.g for col a and row C, we have ```0.010208``` and ``` -0.074151```. I cant pick these values from the original table/dataframe.

Comment: Hey sammywemmy, thank you for the reply and sorry for the confusion. You are right. I corrected the table.